# Show "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" (with Maven) when using "Code Runner"

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am using VS Code with Maven to learn Java (my javac -version is 11.0.10) under macOS Big Sur.

It is ok when I run the code in the terminal by using "RUN," which show on the list of VS Code. However, it always shows the error "Could Not Find Or Load Main Class"(actually in Chinese "找不到或無法載入主要類別 hello") and the reason "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/seifert/learnjava8/hello (wrong name: hello)".

As you can see, the .java file is just a straightforward one to show"hello world."
[the whole screen image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZxos.png)

Had anyone who uses Code Runner met this problem before? How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's the full command on the line starting with `[Running]`?

Comment: @tgdavies Code Runner is an extension(or so-called "plugin") for VSCode. Theoretically, it supports over 40 program languages includes JAVA and can run the user's programs only by using the mouse's left button to choose "Run Code" without typing any command. Please consider the introduction and reference about it as follow link: [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

Comment: If you look at your screenshot, you'll see that the first line of the output appears to be a command that Code Runner has generated to run your program. There must be something about that command which causes the error message you are getting, but without seeing the command we can't tell what it is.

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you for the mention. The whole message of the first line of the output is "[Running] cd "/Users/seiferthan/Dropbox/macAirCoding101/JAVA/Jave8Maven/learnjava8/src/main/java/org/seifert/learnjava8/ch3/" && javac UsingNumber.java && java UsingNumber
".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because it must be called with its fully qualified name.  To be clear, the name of this class is not `hello`, It's `org.seifert.learnjava8.hello`. I create a simple maven project, so the right execution command is:

1. Turn to the folder java: `cd src\main\java`
2. Compile the .java file: `javac org\seifert\learnjava8\hello.java`
3. Run the java file: `java org.seifert.learnjava8.hello`
   [image]

When it comes to run the java file by Code Runner, the execution commands is

```
"code-runner.executorMap":{
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
}
```

The `$dir` represents the direct path to current opened file, and the `javac` and `java` command doesn't include the package to be compiled together, then caused the error:
[image]

So the **solution** is turning to the settings and edit the `"code-runner.executorMap"`:

```
"code-runner.executorMap":{
        "java": "cd /users/seiferthan/.../src/main/java && javac org/seifert/learnjava8/$fileName && java org.seifert.learnjava8.$fileNameWithoutExt",
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer and detail. Following your direction, I changed my setting of "code-runner.executorMap" in Code Runner to be ""java": "cd /Users/seiferthan/Dropbox/macAirCoding101/JAVA/Jave8Maven/learnjava8/src/main/java && javac org/seifert/learnjava8/ch3/$fileName && java org.seifert.learnjava8.ch3.$fileNameWithoutExt",

It seems that we have to change the path of the setting when we change the folder(due to learning different topics or chapters).

Anyway, I have to wholeheartedly thank you again for helping me to resolve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of it isn't called by its "fully qualified name". The project has to be called as `hello.java` rather than simply `hello`. The execution command for your file should be:
`java <directory in which your file lies> hello.java`

So your error should have looked like this:
[The error is shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDFCe.jpg).
And if you use `.java` then, the problem can be solved as:
[The solved program is in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqrsn.jpg)

As you mentioned you use code runner. Follow the steps:

1. Head over to the setting of your vscode and search for code runner and find

> Coderunner: Executor Map

2. Click on "Edit in settings.json"
   [Settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaaij.jpg).
3. Look for java as: [java in settings.json page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS0Wh.png)

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
 }
```

4. Just add `.java` at the end of the line inside the Double quotes WITHOUT ANY SPACE. Then, save it.

```JSON
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt.java",
}
```

5. Now run your program. You are good to go!